# Theorem : Dunford-Pettis Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, optimal-control

[image]

I don't understand  why : there exists a function $g_y(.)\in L^{\infty}(0,T)$ with :
$$
\langle Bf,y\rangle=\int_{0}^{T}{f(t)g_y(t)dt}.\qquad (12.2.7)
$$

$$
\|g_y\|_{L^{\infty}(0,T)}\leq\|B\|_{(L^{1}(0,T),X^{*})}\|y\|_{X}\qquad (12.2.8)
$$

Comment: Can you please cite the book or paper that this page comes from?

Comment: https://books.google.co.ma/books?id=ulcVqwtOp9IC&printsec=frontcover&dq=infinite+dimensional+optimization+and+control+theory&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI9rPd3-jnAhXy8OAKHSmVAgMQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=infinite%20dimensional%20optimization%20and%20control%20theory&f=false

Answer (score 3):

This is immediate from the fact that dual of $L^{1}$ is $L^{\infty}$. The norm of $g_y$ you get from this duality is $ \leq \sup \{|\langle Bf , y \rangle|: \|f\|_1 \le1 \} \leq \|B\|\|y\|_X$

Comment: But why $(12.2.7)$?

Comment: That is what the duality $(L^{1})^{*}=L^{\infty}$ means. If $F$ is a continuous linear functional on $L^{1}$ the there exists $g \in L^{\infty}$ such that $F(f)=\int fg$ for all $f \in L^{1}$. @KarimKHAN

Comment: thank you sir for your reply